# Google App Script command for automatic editing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry but I don't understand much about programming.
I'm trying to merge two codes and make them autonomous in functioning when a new response arrives from the google form.

Everything works except this part:
**function onEdit1(e)**
in this case the RANDOM code is general if I directly modify the sheet, instead I would like the activation to be done automatically each time a new response is sent.

What code should I use?
Thank you very much indeed.

Mauro

```
var SHEETNAME = "Compleanno2024"
var ID_COLUMN = 13;
var ID_LENGHT = 4;


function randomID () {
  var ALPHABET = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  var rtn = '2024-';
  for (var i = 0; i < ID_LENGHT; i++)  {
    rtn += ALPHABET.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ALPHABET.length));
  }
  return rtn;
}


function onEdit(e) {
  onEdit1(e)
  onEdit2(e)
}  

function onEdit1(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if(row>1 && col==7){
    as.getRange(row, 13).setValue(randomID());
  }
}

function onEdit2(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var responseArray = e.values;
    var countryCode = "39";

    //For this part, you just need to change the index[] to the specific column of mobile number in your spreadsheet, count starting from 0, equivalent to column A. 
    //In my sample, the column of mobile number on my spreadsheet is at column G, so the index I indicated was 6.
    responseArray[6] = countryCode + e.values[6]; 
    //A Range object is representing the cell or range of cells that were last added/inputted in the spreadsheet from the form.
    range.setValues([responseArray]);
}
```

**I attach an example file...**
In the second line the fields were taken from the Google form submission and the unique code was not generated. Column M

In line 3 I only copied a part of my telephone number, entering it manually, and in column M the unique code of the "function onEdit1(e) {" appeared

[image]

Comment: `Can you share with us a sample of your desired output?` onEdit1(e) works on my side. However, with onEdit2(e), I encountered an error (specifically on the line `responseArray[6] = countryCode + e.values[6];`) since using `variable[n]` means that you are expecting an array input of `n elements`. If you initially planned for the input to be one entry at a time, then please consider not using the `[6]` index.

Comment: By any chance, was this code generated by ChatGPT or Bard? If so, please take note that not all AI generated codes work and need to be verified before use.

Comment: Patrick thanks for your comment.
I edited the message and inserted an example.

The code I have is the only one of two different codes but I don't think they were generated by ChatGPT.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In `the second line the fields were taken from the Google form submission and the unique code was not generated`, this is because onEdit cannot detect this as a new change. For inputs from form submissions, you must use the installable trigger [form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: May I confirm if the spreadsheet that you use is the repository of that said Google Forms? On Form Submit triggers only work when the spreadsheet is bound to a Google Forms.

Comment: Patrick, what do you mean by google sheet "repository"?

Patrick thanks so much for your suggestion. Since I have little programming experience, I ask you for a great courtesy. How should I modify the code? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I will post an answer and we'll work it from there.

Comment: What i meant with the repository is that if the google sheets that you are using the code with is where the raw data from the Google Forms are dumped. Usually, there is a google sheet that is bound to a google form which acts as a dump for raw data.

Comment: Yes, I am using the codes on the sheet connected to the Google form, where all the raw data from the compilation ends up.

Comment: I have posted an answer below. kindly check if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use an Installable Trigger with On Form Submit

The simple trigger onEdit(e) will not work with Google Form entries. Instead, use an installable trigger with on form submit event type.

Delete:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  onEdit1(e)
  onEdit2(e)
}
```

### <--- Update --->

You can combine both onEditN() functions into one so that you will only need to setup one On Form Submit trigger. Your code should look like this:

```
var SHEETNAME = "Compleanno2024"
var ID_COLUMN = 13;
var ID_LENGHT = 4;


function randomID () {
  var ALPHABET = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  var rtn = '2024-';
  for (var i = 0; i < ID_LENGHT; i++)  {
    rtn += ALPHABET.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ALPHABET.length));
  }
  return rtn;
}

function onEditCombined(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var responseArray = e.values;
    var countryCode = "39";

    //For this part, you just need to change the index[] to the specific column of mobile number in your spreadsheet, count starting from 0, equivalent to column A. 
    //In my sample, the column of mobile number on my spreadsheet is at column G, so the index I indicated was 6.
    responseArray[6] = countryCode + e.values[6]; 
    range.setValues([responseArray]);

    const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const row = e.range.getRow();
    if (row > 1 && responseArray[6] != "") {
      as.getRange(row, 13).setValue(randomID());
    }

}
```

And then add an installable trigger for each of your remaining onEditN(e) functions. You may do it by clicking on triggers:

[image]

And then `+ Add Trigger` (lower right button). After wards, use the following setup for your onEdit1(e) and onEdit2(e):

[image]

The triggers page should then look like this:

[image]

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Feel free to comment if the answer still lacks information or still does not work on your side.

Comment: I have now modified the script as you advised me and added the two triggers "OnEdit1" and "OnEdit2".
By experimenting "OnEdit2" is executed. While "OnEdit1" does not generate any code. Empty box (Column M)

The triggers do not generate any errors
:-(

Comment: Have you tried combining the two codes under one function? I.e. place the code of onedit1 inside onedit2 since onedit2 is already functioning? Also, can you update the code in your post so that i may try and fix it as well?

Comment: I have added an update to the code. I combined both onEditN() functions into one so that you will only need to setup one On Form Submit trigger instead of two. Kindly check if it works on your side @MauroMancini

Comment: Perfect. Now it works great.
You were magnificent. A huge thank you.
Mauro

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I think it was better to use only one trigger for your case because I assumed you encountered a bug when there were two.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code changed as per your instruction...

```
var SHEETNAME = "Compleanno2024"
var ID_COLUMN = 13;
var ID_LENGHT = 4;


function randomID () {
  var ALPHABET = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  var rtn = '2024-';
  for (var i = 0; i < ID_LENGHT; i++)  {
    rtn += ALPHABET.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ALPHABET.length));
  }
  return rtn;
}


function onEdit1(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if(row>1 && col==7){
    as.getRange(row, 13).setValue(randomID());
  }
}

function onEdit2(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var responseArray = e.values;
    var countryCode = "39";

    //For this part, you just need to change the index[] to the specific column of mobile number in your spreadsheet, count starting from 0, equivalent to column A. 
    //In my sample, the column of mobile number on my spreadsheet is at column G, so the index I indicated was 6.
    responseArray[6] = countryCode + e.values[6]; 
    //A Range object is representing the cell or range of cells that were last added/inputted in the spreadsheet from the form.
    range.setValues([responseArray]);
}
```

[image]